# c# method constrained return type

Tags: c#

I've been trying to do something in my code that I would like the opinion of someone more experienced.

So, I have a few class types that have the following structure:

```
abstract class BaseType<T> where T : CustomObj
{
    public List<T> SomeProperty { get; protected set; }
    public void AddSomeProperty(T property)
        {
            SomeProperty.Add(property);
        }
}

class ChildClassA : BaseType<ExtendedCustomObj>
{
    public ChildClassA() 
    {
        SomeProperty = new List<ExtendedCustomObj>();
    }
}

class ChildClassB : BaseType<CustomObj>
{
    public ChildClassB()
    {
        SomeProperty  = new List<CustomObj>();
    }
}

public CustomObj { }
public ExtendedCustomObj : CustomObj { }
```

Then I have a method on another class, that acts almost like a factory/construtor that receives data in JSON format and returns either a ChildClassA or a ChildClassB. As they are both extending BaseType, that is what I was intending to use as a return type.

```
private static BaseType ProcessJSONPayload(StreamReader reader)
{
   if(condition A)
      return new ChildClassA();
   else
      return new ChildClassB();
}
```

However, BaseType here is missing the generic specification.
So I've tried something like:

```
private static BaseType<CustomObj> ProcessJSONPayload(StreamReader reader)
{
   ...{Same code as above}
}
```

This will result in the compiler complaining "Cannot implicitly convert type 'ChildClassA' to 'BaseType'"as ChildClassA uses an extended CustomObject instead of it directly.

If I didn't have BaseType as generic, I would just say I'm returning BaseType, even though that would create some abstraction in code after it as I would have to be validating the actual type.
But having it as generic with the constraint is helping me on some places.

My code is in the end receiving different configurations via JSON that result on instantiating different objects.

Any idea how to go around this compiler error?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you mixing up `BaseClass` and `BaseType`?

Comment: _"As they are both extending BaseClass, that is what I was intending to use as a return type"_ -- your two types don't extend the same type. They extend two different types, `BaseType<ExtendedCustomObj>` and `BaseType<CustomObj>`. These two types are not the same, nor are they even related. To understand why, see marked duplicate, which addresses the crux of this otherwise-too-broad question. If you want to return a common base type, you need to come up with a common base type first. Nothing in your question suggests that's feasible, so more likely the method itself should be generic.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen YEs, sorry, I changed the class types to make this post, I will fix it on the main post. I meant BaseType

Comment: @PeterDuniho They are, ExtendedCustomObj extends CustomObj, I didn't put them in the question I though it was implicit. As such a ExtendedCustomObj extending CustomObj it has all its properties and methods, so on my view, the compiler should accept it.

Comment: _"ExtendedCustomObj extends CustomObj"_ -- you are missing the point. The fact that `ExtendedCustomObj` inherits `CustomObj` does not mean then that `BaseType<ExtendedCustomObj>` inherits `BaseType<CustomObj>`. See marked duplicate, as well as [the hundreds of other questions on Stack Overflow involving generic type variance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+generic+variance). Most of them are just variations of the same misunderstanding you have.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Ok, I think I understand now what you mean, is not about the generic type used, the 'T' so to say, but the BaseType itself as they will be technically different objects. I'm more used to Typescript where a long as things match they are almost the same, but C# is not Typescript. 
What recommendations would you have so a I can achieve the functionality I've mentioned? Using an Interface?

Comment: You can't achieve what you want. It's not safe. Typescript only allows it because it's not type-safe. At runtime, the code could fail with an invalid cast or missing member or something like that (I'm surprised to hear it would work in Typescript, because I thought the point of that was to bring static typing to the unsafe JavaScript language, but I'll take your word for it). ...

Comment: ... You either need to provide the exact type at the caller (i.e. assuming the caller needs to access members of the object), or come up with some alternative base type (even `object` would do, assuming you don't need to actually _use_ the object).